# CSS animations with transform: translate

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms

Please help, when I'm trying to play animation with moving ball in position X and Y at the same time it doesn't work, some strange behaviour. I would like to look like a batted and falling ball

```css
.ball {
  position: absolute;
  left: 18%;
  bottom: 100px;

  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  border-radius: 50%;

  animation: fly-ball-x 2s, fly-ball-y 2s;
}

@keyframes fly-ball-x {
100% {
  transform: translateX(300px);
  }
}

@keyframes fly-ball-y {
100% {
  transform: translateY(100px);
  }
}
<div class="ball"></div>

**The result I'm expecting is like the code below:**

@keyframes fly-ball-x {
100% {
  left: 300px;
 }
}

@keyframes fly-ball-y {
100% {
  bottom: 0;
 }
}

.ball {
  position: absolute;
  left: 18%;
  bottom: 100px;

  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  border-radius: 50%;

  animation: fly-ball-x 2s cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.67, 0.6, 1), fly- 
  ball-y 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="ball"></div>
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Expected result is the ball is moving on X and Y position at the same time using transform translate x, y

Comment: The problem here is that `fly-ball-y` "reset" the X value as it has no translateX value. I can't see how to do it except with a single animation, which is clearly not whet you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.ball {
  position: absolute;
  left: 18%;
  bottom: 100px;

  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  border-radius: 50%;

  animation: fly-ball 2s
}

@keyframes fly-ball {
100% {
  transform: translateX(300px) translateY(100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ball"></div>
```

It is because you weren't running the animations concurrently. Here both translations are just being run at the same time. You just had a bit more than you needed.

**EDIT**

Check out this blog post. It gives explanations on the kinds of curves it seems you are going for [Curved Path Animations In CSS](https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/curved-path-animations-in-css/)

Comment: See my edited post. I hope it will help to understand better what I mean. The example with Left and Bottom works but I know for animations we should use transform

Comment: @Radek Take a look at my edit and see if it helps you at all